# Any downsides in giving a participant A and B then compare the results?

Tags: experiment-design, case-control-study, research-design

Almost all the experimental design studies that I came across randomly separates participants into bucket A or B. Then they study the effects to identify a causal relationship.

Are there any downsides to assigning all participants both A and B 100 times (50 times each randomly)? The number of times is arbitrary..it can be 1000x (500:500) but you get the point.

Isn't that a better way to identify whether there is a casual relationship? Let's assume that the participants don't realized that there are 2 variations.

Comment: Only if you assume there is no interaction with treatment B if you've had treatment A first, or visa versa. Look up: washout period.

Comment: If you don't think A and B influence each other, but aren't sure: maybe give A first to group 1 and B first to group 2; compare groups. Then if you're right you have a paired experiment, potentially with greater power. (If A and B are two OTC pain relievers with effects lasting only a few hours, then separating A and B by a couple of days ought to ensure no interaction. But if A and B are blood pressure medications that take a while to have effect and a while to wear off, then probably best to do a 2-sample expt from the start. If A and B involve learning something, 2-sample is the only way.)